# How to apply parse failure tag only when message fails BOTH filters instead of just one?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-json

My logtash config has two filters: 1) parses a log message and 2) parses a JSON message:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" =>
    "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_time}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}(?<space>\s*)\]\[%{DATA:thread_name}\]\[%{DATA:class_name}\]%{GREEDYDATA:log_msg}" }
  }
  json {
    source => "message"
    add_tag => ["RiskExplain"]
  }
}
```

At the moment, if a JSON message is logged, it'll fail the grok filter before being parsed by the json filter. Because it failed the first filter, it'll receive a `_grokparsefailure` tag. I'd like to remove this tag and only apply a parse failure tag if it fails BOTH filters. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
grok {
  match => { "message" =>
    "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_time}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}(?<space>\s*)\]\[%{DATA:thread_name}\]\[%{DATA:class_name}\]%{GREEDYDATA:log_msg}" }
}
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
  json {
    source => "message"
    add_tag => ["RiskExplain"]
    tag_on_failure => ["The_Tag_You_Want"]
    remove_tag => [ "_grokparsefailure" ]
  }
}
```

This way the json filter will only used when the grok filter failed to parse the message. The json filter will remove the `_grokparsefailure` tag and if it fails, will add the `The_Tag_You_Want` tag.